# What is the minimum VM Budget Size?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, virtual-machine

Short Version:

Is there a guaranteed minimum VM Budget Size (or at least a reasonable target)? I am exceeding it with an xml layout that is nothing but a linearlayout wrapping a single 30KB image.

Long version:

I'm getting the following error related to bitmap exceeding vm budget:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dah.rh/com.dah.rh.activities.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2649)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:131)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1975)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4702)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:208)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1629)
   at com.dah.rh.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:26)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2587)
   ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:105)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
   ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:464)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:340)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:549)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:115)
   ... 26 more
```

The line in the stacktrace that is my code is the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash_page);
```

From here, Android attempts to inflate the resource splash_page.xml listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The image "logo.png" is a 240x138px png sizing in at 30KB.  It seems strange to me that this would exceed the budget whereas other pages where I have loaded 6 images totaling over 35KB total have not exceeded the budget.  It seems like the only thing I can do is to shrink the image, but I have no idea how small to make it.

Comment: Maybe your PNG file is corrupt? Try editing it and saving a new copy of it... (shot in the dark here)

Comment: Is there anything in the "adb logcat" output that indicates the cause of the failure?  Doesn't look like an OOM situation.

Comment: @fadden: The stacktrace above is from the logcat output, and it's definitely an out of memory as the root cause is "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"

Comment: @Damp: I don't think this is the case, as the png works fine on my device and the various avds I have tested on.  I am getting this stacktrace via Android Remote Stacktrace (http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) and cannot reproduce this issue locally.

Comment: Apparently I don't know how vertical scrollbars work.  Anyway, in the logcat above the exception you should see something indicating the size of the allocation that failed.  You can also use gclog.py (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/146a3a354ce3e8e3/61e113036089d696#61e113036089d696) to see where the memory is going.  If it's primarily managed heap, you can use android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData() to get a heap dump.

Comment: @fadden: Thanks for the help.  I'm unable to reproduce the issue locally, but if I can, I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum budget, so to speak, is 16MB, insofar as the smallest maximum heap size for an Android application is 16MB. You are not exceeding it with a single PNG file of the size you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not sure what else could be causing the issue, as I'm not allocating any memory before calling setContentView.  In fact, it is the second call in my onCreate function after the call to the super.onCreate.